# Tutorial for Google Fit API not working

Tags: google-fit

I tried this tutorial https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started.

When I repeat the same process for Gmail API it works, but when I try the fit API I always get 500 backendError.

I try to call https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources. But I always get:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 500, 
        "message": "Backend Error", 
        "errors": [
          {
            "domain": "global", 
            "message": "Backend Error", 
            "reason": "backendError"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to see what data I have in Google Fit, because the results are inconsistent with other apps.

Comment: Did you read the note `Note that the access token will expire after 60 minutes (3600 seconds).`?  How exactly are you calling the url?

Comment: Through the developer console https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/. I think something got broken, because my Google FIT does not sync with the web anymore.

Comment: The access token was 100% valid at the time. I went back and forth between Gmail and Fit and got always a normal response from Gmail and 500 from Fit.

Comment: Can you try the tutorial on your google account?

Answer (score 0):

I think something is broken either on my account or in the rest API. When I set these scopes it works and the URL returns existing datasets:

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write
```

When I set these scopes it returns backendError:

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.write
```

The synchronisation between my app and web interface is also broken. I have sent a feedback to Google. It showed weird values on the Dashboard before this happened.

[image: google fit rest broken]

**Edit**: It works now if I click on both fitness.activity and fitness.nutrition but something is obviously broken somewhere.

I also accessed the datasets and the data, which is in the raw datasets has nothing to do with the data that is displayed the next day in the timeline. I connected google fit with cronometer and during the day the nutrition values in google fit were correct and the next day they were totally different. I have no idea where the nutrition data in the web comes from.